# using google analytics to log ajax errors

Tags: jquery, google-analytics

I have the following code which is supposed to send a notification on ajax error to the user, and as a snap-solution, I decided to use google analytics to log those errors, however it doesn't work, does anyone have an idea/lead or must I implement a different solution?

`showNotification(title, message)` is a custom dialog box invoker.

```
$(document).ajaxError(function(e, xhr, settings) {
    $(".modal").modal('hide');
    showNotification('Something went wrong...', 'Whoa there! Something happened which we didn\'t predict, we sent ourselves a notification. ');
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'AjaxError', xhr.status, settings.url]);
});
```

it works in the sense that it shows the notification, but it doesn't send an event to analytics.
any leads?

Comment: Do you know if Analytics is invoked? You could check it if you use fiddler

Comment: invoked in the sense that it sends a request? than no, it doesn't send a request. in the sense that there's _gaq initialized?  than yes.

Comment: The push function is inside a try statement, maybe you could attatch a debugger and see whats happining inside.

Comment: Try switching the order of `showNotification` and `_gaq.push`. If that doesn't work, you could incorporate the `_gaq.push` into the `showNotification` function based on `title`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `xhr.status` is an integer, and typically 0.  The second argument to `trackEvent` is supposed to be a string, and apparently if it's integer 0, Google ignores the call.  So using `statusText` fixes it:

```
$(document).ajaxError(function(e, xhr, settings) {
    // Generic Google error logging
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'AjaxError', xhr.statusText, settings.url]);

    // Application-specific UI code
    $(".modal").modal('hide');
    showNotification('Something went wrong...', 'Whoa there! Something happened which we didn\'t predict, we sent ourselves a notification. ');
});
```

Also, I'd recommend putting the GA call before your code since (no offense) Google's code is less likely to error out.

Great idea, BTW!

Answer (score 0):

You may have another error happening somewhere else in your code.  I have mocked up a sample of this functionality here, and it works:

http://jsbin.com/emocah/edit#preview

Did you just start tracking this?  Sometimes new events take a few days to propagate in GA.  Also, are there any other JS errors that occur on your page?